# No data recovered with sequelize-oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

I am using [sequelize-oracle](https://github.com/lebretr/sequelize-oracle) to query with NodeJS over Oracle.

I have the following model:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-oracle');
var User = sequelize.define('user', {        
        uid: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
};
```

I have the following query:

```
User.findAll().then(function(rows) {
    callback(null, rows);
}).catch(function(error) {
    callback(error);
});
```

When I execute it, the SQL generated is correct:

```
SELECT id, uid, name FROM user user;
```

but I get no data in the result JSON:

```
[
{ },
{ },
{ },
{ }
]
```

However, if I try to execute a raw query, these data are recovered:

```
var connection = new Sequelize(/* ... */);
connection.query('SELECT id, uid, name FROM user user').then(function(rows) {
    callback(null, rows[0]);
}).catch(function(error) {
    callback(error);
});
```

And the result:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    uid: 12345,
    name: "user1"
}, {
    id: 2,
    uid: 67890,
    name: "user2"
}, {
    id: 3,
    uid: 11111,
    name: "user3"
}, {
    id: 4,
    uid: 22222,
    name: "user4"
}]
```

Any ideas?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

sequelize-oracle hasn't been updated for close to half a year, and is more than 500 commits behind the master branch - try this fork instead, which is more current https://github.com/gintsgints/sequelize